# Limit the number of words in a div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is there a css property that can limit the number of characters to be displayed in a div.For example

```
<div class ="main-text">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

but I need to display only

```
<div class ="main-text">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
</div>
```

I am using wordpress site with testimonial feature. So if any customer adds a testimonial, I need to display only the first few words with the link. Please Help!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play around with a `overflow` property (actually there are couple of them - `overflow-x, overflow-y` and `overflow`), also you have to set the `width` in absolute units (read pixels or em,  but **not** in percentage) of your `div`.

For example (CSS):

```
div.main-text {overflow-x: hidden;width: 200px;} 
/*This will hide everything, which goes outside of the 200px div*/
```

Also you can limit your text with simple PHP code:

```
if (!function_exists('chop_string')) {
function chop_string($str, $len) {
    if (strlen($str) < $len)
        return $str;

    $str = substr($str,0,$len);
    if ($spc_pos = strrpos($str," "))
            $str = substr($str,0,$spc_pos);

    return $str . "Read more...";
}   
}
```

Place the above function in your Wordpress theme's `functions.php` file and use it like this:

`<?php echo chop_string('Bla bla bla', 5); ?>`

The above code will show only 5 characters from your string and `Read more...`.

EDIT:

If you want to cut the title or the generated content which comes from Wordpress, then you have to edit your `page.php` file (also `archive.php` file), they are inside your template directory. Find the following code in those files: `the_content()` and `the_title()`, **those 2 functions display actually all information** from database.

So cut them like this:
`<?php echo chop_string(the_title(), 5); ?>` or 
`<?php echo chop_string(the_content(), 5); ?>`

Comment: Wher should i add this <?php echo chop_string('Bla bla bla', 5); ?> .Also sorry to ask is bla bla bla the text to limitin your example?

Comment: Yes, the text in the code is only example. Place the `<?php echo chop_string('your real text here', 5); ?>` in the page template, where you want to cut the text.

Comment: but im in a wordpress site. the text is automatically generated

Comment: the text what actualy i have to chop comes in $content . So if I add the code like this <?php echo chop_string($content, 5); ?> work? or $content = chop_string($content, 5); and then echo $content .please help!!

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways you can achieve this :

1) **CSS way**

add the css property **text-overflow:ellipsis**

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

2) **Trick way (HTML)**

add a **textarea** control inside the `div and add **maxlength=50**` or whatever you need , hide the border using the **css** `border:none` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css ellipsis. Just use it on the text-overflow. It will truncate adapt to the width of you box.

http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

```
.main-text {
  width: 250px;

}

.main-text p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

One limitation is that you are restricted to use one row.

Comment: One suggestion instead of posting a link paste relevant Code here.

Comment: This one seems too close.Any suggestion to make it more than one row?

Comment: @user3488898 many people use this jQuery plugin http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/ (dotdotdot). In pure CSS its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS is presentational, so not involved with the length of specific content. It can clip on presentational properties such as box size with the `overflow` and `text-overflow` properties, but not based on content. You can easily fix it on the server side though:

```
$text = strlen($text) > 250 ? substr($text, 0, 250).'&hellip;' : $text;
echo "<p>$text</p>";
```

This inserts an ellipsis after 250 characters if the text is longer than that.

Comment: Funny how the only answer that actually answers the question (limit by character/word count) gets drive-by downvoted without comment while all the other answers solve another problem (limit by container size).

Comment: Where can i add this?

Comment: In the serverside code where the content is generated.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of CSS3 property "text-overflow" - you can set the box width, thus resulting with the exact width for ALL divs;

Text won't be cut in the middle of the word and it will add "..." at the end of the text, hinting it's a preview text;

HTML Code:

```
<div id="myDiv">Just some text - you won't see ME!</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#myDiv {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 256px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Tested under FF, Chrome, IE11

Comment: This has been suggested in several answers. The original poster does not want to limit him self to one row witch "text-overflow: ellipsis" does.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution demo: [limit-printed-words.html](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/thoqbk/scriptbucket/blob/master/public_html/limit-printed-words.html)

It works well with **any nested level and even button content**.

---

[image]

---

Source project: [scriptbucket](https://github.com/thoqbk/scriptbucket)